# parsing xml from web service call in java

Tags: c#, java, android, xml-serialization

I apologise if this is a duplicate thread...

I have a c# web service where I return an xml object that I need to parse into a Hashmap in my android application, the returned object from the service is .Net type Dictionary

most of the other calls are returning json which I can parse into a JsonObject with the response string but this particular call needs to return xml for other apps

could anyone please advise whats the simplest way to go out parsing xml returned from a web service into java objects or at least be able to maybe create an xml document from the response and pull values out of that?

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly two ways and based on your requirement you need to choose one.

1) SAX parser: Mainly useful if you want to read all elements in XML document and create java objects. Here is a referene. [SAXParsing](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/). This is less memory consuming approach because entire xml file won't be cached while processing.

2) DOM parser: This is useful when you want to read specific parts of the xml (you can use this to parse entire file, but I use more when I need to play with part of the xml). This is more memory consuming approach, because entire xml file will be cached while processing. Here is an example. [Dom parsing](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

You may use Sun inbuilt API for these parsing mechanisms (or) there are other third party APIs like Apache etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Try [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)  or [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)